# eliminate unwanted data from list using python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a list like this.how can i eliminate **\xe2\x80\x99,\xe2\x80\x9c etc** from my list using python. is there anyway to eliminate these kind of data from my list??
common pattern is avilable?

> ['guest', 'demo', ':', 'eric', 'iverson', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'itty',
>   'bitty', 'search', 'february', '16', 'th', ',', '2010', 'by',
>   'daniel', 'tunkelang', 'respond', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99m', 'back',
>   'from', 'vacation', ',', 'and', 'still', 'digging', 'my', 'way',
>   'out', 'of', 'everything', 'that', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'piled', 'up',
>   'while', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99ve', 'been', 'offline', 'while', 'i',
>   'catch', 'up', ',', 'i', 'thought', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99d', 'share',
>   'with', 'you', 'a', 'demo', 'that', 'eric', 'iverson', 'was',
>   'gracious', 'enough', 'to', 'share', 'with', 'me', 'it', 'uses',
>   'yahoo', '!', 'boss', 'to', 'support', 'an', 'exploratory', 'search',
>   'experience', 'on', 'top', 'of', 'a', 'general', 'web', 'search',
>   'engine', 'when', 'you', 'perform', 'a', 'query', ',', 'the',
>   'application', 'retrieves', 'a', 'set', 'of', 'related', 'term',
>   'candidates', 'using', 'yahoo', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'key', 'terms',
>   'api', 'it', 'then', 'scores', 'each', 'term', 'by', 'dividing', 'it',
>   'is', 'occurrence', 'count', 'within', 'the', 'result', 'set', 'by',
>   'it', 'is', 'global', 'occurrence', 'count', '\xe2\x80\x93a',
>   'relevance', 'measure', 'similar', 'to', 'one', 'my', 'former',
>   'colleagues', 'and', 'i', 'used', 'at', 'endeca', 'in', 'enterprise',
>   'contexts', 'you', 'can', 'try', 'out', 'the', 'demo', 'yourself',
>   'at', 'http', '://www', 'ittybittysearch', 'com', '/', 'while', 'it',
>   'has', 'rough', 'edges', ',', 'it', 'produces', 'nice', 'results',
>   '\xe2\x80\x93especially', 'considering', 'the', 'simplicity', 'of',
>   'the', 'approach', 'here', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'an', 'example', 'of',
>   'how', 'i', 'used', 'the', 'application', 'to', 'explore', 'and',
>   'learn', 'something', 'new', 'i', 'started', 'with', '["',
>   'information', 'retrieval', '"]', 'i', 'noticed', '\xe2\x80\x9c',
>   'interactive', 'information', 'retrieval', '\xe2\x80\x9d', 'as', 'a',
>   'top', 'term', ',', 'so', 'i', 'used', 'it', 'to', 'refine', 'most',
>   'of', 'the', 'refinement', 'suggestions', 'looked', 'familiar', 'to',
>   'me', '\xe2\x80\x93but', 'an', 'unfamiliar', 'name', 'caught', 'my',
>   'attention', ':', '\xe2\x80\x9c', 'anton', 'leuski', '\xe2\x80\x9d',
>   'following', 'my', 'curiosity', ',', 'i', 'refined', 'again',
>   'looking', 'at', 'the', 'results', ',', 'i', 'immediately', 'saw',
>   'that', 'leuski', 'had', 'done', 'work', 'on', 'evaluating',
>   'document', 'clustering', 'for', 'interactive', 'information',
>   'retrieval', 'further', 'exploration', 'made', 'it', 'clear', 'this',
>   'is', 'someone', 'whose', 'work', 'i', 'should', 'get', 'to', 'know',
>   '\xe2\x80\x93check', 'out', 'his', 'home', 'page', '!', 'i', 'can',
>   '\xe2\x80\x99t', 'promise', 'that', 'you', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'have',
>   'as', 'productive', 'an', 'experience', 'as', 'i', 'did', ',', 'but',
>   'i', 'encourage', 'you', 'to', 'try', 'eric', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'demo',
>   'it', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'simple', 'examples', 'like', 'these', 'that',
>   'remind', 'me', 'of', 'the', 'value', 'of', 'pursuing', 'hcir', 'for',
>   'the', 'open', 'web', 'speaking', 'of', 'which', ',', 'hcir', '2010',
>   'is', 'in', 'the', 'works', 'we', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'flesh', 'out',
>   'the', 'details', 'over', 'the', 'next', 'weeks', ',', 'and', 'of',
>   'course', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'share', 'them', 'here']

Comment: You need to know the encoding

Comment: i have added a statement like below on the top of my program # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: Those "kind of data" are regular strings. E.g. is `\xe2\x80\x99s` is `’s`.

Comment: No you're missing the point, you need to know the encoding of the CONTENT because that has been lost earlier on.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, it has to be encoded somehow. Only that some users don't think about encoding as long as they work only with "standard latin characters". But even those (the characters not the users) have to be encoded. Be it ascii, EBCDIC, utf-8 or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I could hazard a guess that the input was utf8 coding, you could do something like this:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> my_list = ['guest', 'demo', ':', 'eric', 'iverson', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'itty', 'bitty', 'search', 'february', '16', 'th', ',', '2010', 'by', 'daniel', 'tunkelang', 'respond', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99m', 'back', 'from', 'vacation', ',', 'and', 'still', 'digging', 'my', 'way', 'out', 'of', 'everything', 'that', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'piled', 'up', 'while', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99ve', 'been', 'offline', 'while', 'i', 'catch', 'up', ',', 'i', 'thought', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99d', 'share', 'with', 'you', 'a', 'demo', 'that', 'eric', 'iverson', 'was', 'gracious', 'enough', 'to', 'share', 'with', 'me', 'it', 'uses', 'yahoo', '!', 'boss', 'to', 'support', 'an', 'exploratory', 'search', 'experience', 'on', 'top', 'of', 'a', 'general', 'web', 'search', 'engine', 'when', 'you', 'perform', 'a', 'query', ',', 'the', 'application', 'retrieves', 'a', 'set', 'of', 'related', 'term', 'candidates', 'using', 'yahoo', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'key', 'terms', 'api', 'it', 'then', 'scores', 'each', 'term', 'by', 'dividing', 'it', 'is', 'occurrence', 'count', 'within', 'the', 'result', 'set', 'by', 'it', 'is', 'global', 'occurrence', 'count', '\xe2\x80\x93a', 'relevance', 'measure', 'similar', 'to', 'one', 'my', 'former', 'colleagues', 'and', 'i', 'used', 'at', 'endeca', 'in', 'enterprise', 'contexts', 'you', 'can', 'try', 'out', 'the', 'demo', 'yourself', 'at', 'http', '://www', 'ittybittysearch', 'com', '/', 'while', 'it', 'has', 'rough', 'edges', ',', 'it', 'produces', 'nice', 'results', '\xe2\x80\x93especially', 'considering', 'the', 'simplicity', 'of', 'the', 'approach', 'here', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'how', 'i', 'used', 'the', 'application', 'to', 'explore', 'and', 'learn', 'something', 'new', 'i', 'started', 'with', '["', 'information', 'retrieval', '"]', 'i', 'noticed', '\xe2\x80\x9c', 'interactive', 'information', 'retrieval', '\xe2\x80\x9d', 'as', 'a', 'top', 'term', ',', 'so', 'i', 'used', 'it', 'to', 'refine', 'most', 'of', 'the', 'refinement', 'suggestions', 'looked', 'familiar', 'to', 'me', '\xe2\x80\x93but', 'an', 'unfamiliar', 'name', 'caught', 'my', 'attention', ':', '\xe2\x80\x9c', 'anton', 'leuski', '\xe2\x80\x9d', 'following', 'my', 'curiosity', ',', 'i', 'refined', 'again', 'looking', 'at', 'the', 'results', ',', 'i', 'immediately', 'saw', 'that', 'leuski', 'had', 'done', 'work', 'on', 'evaluating', 'document', 'clustering', 'for', 'interactive', 'information', 'retrieval', 'further', 'exploration', 'made', 'it', 'clear', 'this', 'is', 'someone', 'whose', 'work', 'i', 'should', 'get', 'to', 'know', '\xe2\x80\x93check', 'out', 'his', 'home', 'page', '!', 'i', 'can', '\xe2\x80\x99t', 'promise', 'that', 'you', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'have', 'as', 'productive', 'an', 'experience', 'as', 'i', 'did', ',', 'but', 'i', 'encourage', 'you', 'to', 'try', 'eric', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'demo', 'it', '\xe2\x80\x99s', 'simple', 'examples', 'like', 'these', 'that', 'remind', 'me', 'of', 'the', 'value', 'of', 'pursuing', 'hcir', 'for', 'the', 'open', 'web', 'speaking', 'of', 'which', ',', 'hcir', '2010', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'works', 'we', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'flesh', 'out', 'the', 'details', 'over', 'the', 'next', 'weeks', ',', 'and', 'of', 'course', 'i', '\xe2\x80\x99ll', 'share', 'them', 'here']
>>> my_clean_list = [unidecode(x.decode('utf8')) for x in my_list]
>>> my_clean_list
['guest', 'demo', ':', 'eric', 'iverson', "'s", 'itty', 'bitty', 'search', 'february', '16', 'th', ',', '2010', 'by', 'daniel', 'tunkelang', 'respond', 'i', "'m", 'back', 'from', 'vacation', ',', 'and', 'still', 'digging', 'my', 'way', 'out', 'of', 'everything', 'that', "'s", 'piled', 'up', 'while', 'i', "'ve", 'been', 'offline', 'while', 'i', 'catch', 'up', ',', 'i', 'thought', 'i', "'d", 'share', 'with', 'you', 'a', 'demo', 'that', 'eric', 'iverson', 'was', 'gracious', 'enough', 'to', 'share', 'with', 'me', 'it', 'uses', 'yahoo', '!', 'boss', 'to', 'support', 'an', 'exploratory', 'search', 'experience', 'on', 'top', 'of', 'a', 'general', 'web', 'search', 'engine', 'when', 'you', 'perform', 'a', 'query', ',', 'the', 'application', 'retrieves', 'a', 'set', 'of', 'related', 'term', 'candidates', 'using', 'yahoo', "'s", 'key', 'terms', 'api', 'it', 'then', 'scores', 'each', 'term', 'by', 'dividing', 'it', 'is', 'occurrence', 'count', 'within', 'the', 'result', 'set', 'by', 'it', 'is', 'global', 'occurrence', 'count', '-a', 'relevance', 'measure', 'similar', 'to', 'one', 'my', 'former', 'colleagues', 'and', 'i', 'used', 'at', 'endeca', 'in', 'enterprise', 'contexts', 'you', 'can', 'try', 'out', 'the', 'demo', 'yourself', 'at', 'http', '://www', 'ittybittysearch', 'com', '/', 'while', 'it', 'has', 'rough', 'edges', ',', 'it', 'produces', 'nice', 'results', '-especially', 'considering', 'the', 'simplicity', 'of', 'the', 'approach', 'here', "'s", 'an', 'example', 'of', 'how', 'i', 'used', 'the', 'application', 'to', 'explore', 'and', 'learn', 'something', 'new', 'i', 'started', 'with', '["', 'information', 'retrieval', '"]', 'i', 'noticed', '"', 'interactive', 'information', 'retrieval', '"', 'as', 'a', 'top', 'term', ',', 'so', 'i', 'used', 'it', 'to', 'refine', 'most', 'of', 'the', 'refinement', 'suggestions', 'looked', 'familiar', 'to', 'me', '-but', 'an', 'unfamiliar', 'name', 'caught', 'my', 'attention', ':', '"', 'anton', 'leuski', '"', 'following', 'my', 'curiosity', ',', 'i', 'refined', 'again', 'looking', 'at', 'the', 'results', ',', 'i', 'immediately', 'saw', 'that', 'leuski', 'had', 'done', 'work', 'on', 'evaluating', 'document', 'clustering', 'for', 'interactive', 'information', 'retrieval', 'further', 'exploration', 'made', 'it', 'clear', 'this', 'is', 'someone', 'whose', 'work', 'i', 'should', 'get', 'to', 'know', '-check', 'out', 'his', 'home', 'page', '!', 'i', 'can', "'t", 'promise', 'that', 'you', "'ll", 'have', 'as', 'productive', 'an', 'experience', 'as', 'i', 'did', ',', 'but', 'i', 'encourage', 'you', 'to', 'try', 'eric', "'s", 'demo', 'it', "'s", 'simple', 'examples', 'like', 'these', 'that', 'remind', 'me', 'of', 'the', 'value', 'of', 'pursuing', 'hcir', 'for', 'the', 'open', 'web', 'speaking', 'of', 'which', ',', 'hcir', '2010', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'works', 'we', "'ll", 'flesh', 'out', 'the', 'details', 'over', 'the', 'next', 'weeks', ',', 'and', 'of', 'course', 'i', "'ll", 'share', 'them', 'here']
```

Here I am using [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module to transform those "fancy" characters into nearest ascii equivalents:

```
>>> for before, after in zip(my_list, my_clean_list):
...     if before != after:
...         print before, ' --> ', after
...         
’s  -->  's
’m  -->  'm
’s  -->  's
’ve  -->  've
’d  -->  'd
’s  -->  's
–a  -->  -a
–especially  -->  -especially
’s  -->  's
“  -->  "
”  -->  "
–but  -->  -but
“  -->  "
”  -->  "
–check  -->  -check
’t  -->  't
’ll  -->  'll
’s  -->  's
’s  -->  's
’ll  -->  'll
’ll  -->  'll
```

As you can probably guess, it looks like some English data was supposed to be split at word boundaries and this was done incorrectly.  If it is your code which generates this data I suggest you solve your issue closer to the source of the problem!

Comment: +1 Especially for the last paragraph. Grab the problem at its root and don't fight symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a bunch of unicode strings you want to eliminate. Just chose the alpha numeric characters in the list like so:

```
>>> filter( lambda m: m.isalnum()  ,p)
```

That should eliminate the unicode stuff ...

The other option is to encode and decode the string directly ...

```
>>> ' '.join(p).decode('ascii', 'ignore').encode('ascii').split()
```

This should do a much better job ...

Comment: 'isalnum' has nothing to do with unicode. `'ם'.isalnum()` is `True` which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension. Assuming you just want to completely remove the elements of your list containing non-alphanumeric characters. If your list was in a variable `a`:

```
[x for x in a if x.isalnum()]
```

Would return the list, minus the elements with `\xe2\x80\x99`, etc.

This is [equivalent to the filter solution](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) mentioned by @ssm, they just got there first with it.